ORA-00001: unique constraint (WKSP_MYSCHEMA.SYS_C00165018598) violated
Error ORA-00001: unique constraint (WKSP_MYSCHEMA.SYS_C00165018598) violated is occured when I'm trying to insert some data to my table named workers.
This is my CREATE TABLE statement:
CREATE TABLE workers(
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    patronymic VARCHAR2(20),
    email VARCHAR2(30),
    salary NUMBER(7,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    bonus NUMBER(6,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    phone_number CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT check_negative_salary CHECK (salary >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT check_negative_bonus CHECK (bonus >= 0)
);

This is the data I want to insert:
INSERT ALL
INTO workers (last_name, first_name, patronymic, email, salary, bonus, phone_number) VALUES ('Jest', 'Warner', null, 'wshrieve0@gov.uk', 758.94, 56.03, '+375448743018')
INTO workers (last_name, first_name, patronymic, email, salary, bonus, phone_number) VALUES ('Mose', 'Red', null, 'rstolberg1@umn.edu', 1082.65, 119.55, '+375257502777')
INTO workers (last_name, first_name, patronymic, email, salary, bonus, phone_number) VALUES ('Stowers', 'Chase', 'Blincowe', 'cblincowe2@youtube.com', 2662.34, 138.64, '+375338380687')
SELECT * FROM dual;

I checked my table via SELECT * FROM workers and there's no data in it.
The problem may be in this line id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, but I don't know if it's true or not.

From the documentation:

Restrictions on Multitable Inserts.
Multitable inserts are subject to the following restrictions:
…
You cannot specify a sequence in any part of a multitable insert statement. A multitable insert is considered a single SQL statement. Therefore, the first reference to NEXTVAL generates the next number, and all subsequent references in the statement return the same number.

An identity column is really just a wrapper around a sequence, so the same restrictions apply.
It’s not quite correct to say you can’t use a sequence - but in practice you can’t, because of this behaviour.
You will have to do separate single inserts, rather than using insert all; either three inserts with values clauses, or insert … select (as @MT0 showed).

The problem is that I need to use at least one INSERT ALL on my tables because of the task, and all of my tables use GENERATED, not a CREATE SEQUENCE. I'll use your solutions on my other tables, but I should use INSERT ALL to insert data on one table anyway.

If they are all generated always then you can only insert a single value, which makes using all pointless, but I guess technically counts. You can’t even insert parent/child together unless you know the system-generated sequence name. You can insert one row into each of several tables still / then they each get a single ID value from their specific sequences; just not more than one row per table. Depends what the tasks is looking for.

Yes, the problem is with the combination of INSERT ALL and an IDENTITY column.
If you change the CREATE TABLE so the that you generate a named constraint for the PRIMARY KEY column:
CREATE TABLE workers(
    id           NUMBER
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                 CONSTRAINT workers__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    first_name   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    patronymic   VARCHAR2(20),
    email        VARCHAR2(30),
    salary       NUMBER(7,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    bonus        NUMBER(6,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    phone_number CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT check_negative_salary CHECK (salary >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT check_negative_bonus CHECK (bonus >= 0)
);

Then the error raised is:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.WORKERS__ID__PK) violated

This appears to be because the IDENTITY value is only being generated once for the INSERT ALL statement and all rows are being assigned the same id value which then violates the PRIMARY KEY constraint.
To get round the error, you can use INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... :
INSERT INTO workers (last_name, first_name, patronymic, email, salary, bonus, phone_number)
SELECT 'Jest', 'Warner', null, 'wshrieve0@gov.uk', 758.94, 56.03, '+375448743018' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mose', 'Red', null, 'rstolberg1@umn.edu', 1082.65, 119.55, '+375257502777' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Stowers', 'Chase', 'Blincowe', 'cblincowe2@youtube.com', 2662.34, 138.64, '+375338380687' FROM DUAL;


If you have a homework task that requires you to use INSERT ALL then, rather than trying to insert multiple rows into one table, you can insert one row into multiple tables:
CREATE TABLE other (
    id           NUMBER
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                 CONSTRAINT other__id__pk PRIMARY KEY
);

Then:
INSERT ALL
INTO workers (id, last_name, first_name, patronymic, email, salary, bonus, phone_number) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Jest', 'Warner', null, 'wshrieve0@gov.uk', 758.94, 56.03, '+375448743018')
INTO other (id) VALUES (DEFAULT)
SELECT * FROM dual;

fiddle
